# How to remove holidays from a range of dates?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of dates in Column A (Sheet1) and I would like to delete the entire row that matches any of the holidays dates found in Sheet2. For example:

**Dates(Column A,Sheet1)**

```
23/12/2019                                
24/12/2019                                
25/12/2019
26/12/2019
27/12/2019
28/12/2019
29/12/2019
```

**Holidays(Column A,Sheet2)**

```
25/12/2019
26/12/2019
```

The rows containing 25th and 26th of December in Sheet 1 should be deleted. Also, there may be months when there are no holidays to be deleted.

I tried the code below. The loop seems to be working, but no rows are deleted.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 For i = lastrow To 7 Step -1
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value, 
         Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A"), 0)) Then 
         Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: What have you tried? This should be relatively easy with a loop/VBA to delete matching rows. (Or, use a filter).

Comment: I don't think a filter would actually delete the rows, just remove them from the visible portion of the spreadsheet. Maybe if the visible rows could be copied to a VBA array, the filter removed and the rows replaced from the array it might work.

Comment: I think closing this question was a bit harsh. Could potentially have answered this to meet needs of op. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wYis8B0ujoozEbRDBZIkhxk45cfDm8016vRzFQtH27s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @BruceWayne I do think it was unfair to close this post. I am new to VBA, so what might seem easy for you, for me is not

Comment: @Isabela I didn't vote to close this, IIRC. That being said, SO isn't a code-writing site. We're here to help you with existing code/formulas. Have you attempted to solve this on your end? If so, update your question with that attempt and any errors that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: You need to qualify th `Cells()` in the lastRow declaration to refer to Sheet1, add `.` before `Cells()`, otherwise it'll use whatever the ActiveSheet is to set that.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried it, but I get an error message. Luckily the code shared below by hod is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub RemoveDates()

Dim RemovalList()

SheetOneLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
SheetTwoLastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Count = 0

'Collect all the dates that need to be removed into a list
For r = 1 To SheetTwoLastRow
    ReDim Preserve RemovalList(0 To Count)
    RemovalList(Count) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & r).Value
    Count = Count + 1
Next

For r = SheetOneLastRow To 1 Step -1
    If IsInArray(Range("A" & r).Value, RemovalList) Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub


Function IsInArray(SearchFor As String, MyArray As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim st As String
    st = "$" & Join(MyArray, "$") & "$"
    IsInArray = InStr(st, "$" & SearchFor & "$") > 0
End Function
```

Hope this helps!